# Is it possible to set Audit_trail parameter to both DB and OS in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, audit

In Oracle database ,we can direct audit records to either db , os or in xml file by using the below command:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET AUDIT_TRAIL= DB SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

But is it possible to direct audit records to both db and os(both) like the below command which results in error:

```
 ALTER SYSTEM SET AUDIT_TRAIL= DB,OS SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/AUDIT_TRAIL.html

Possible values:

- none
- os
- db
- db, extended
- xml
- xml, extended

More details can be found on the above link.

Comment: Can we combine the parameters ?

Comment: @Allan No. Above is a list of possible values,they can not be combined.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative to store audit records in both db and os at the same time?

Comment: @Allan Not that is native to Oracle DB. You can use other Oracle tools like Audit Vault or 3rd party tools like Splunk to read the audit trail from the database tables or XML files and store it separately. Also note that the audit trail that is written to using the "OS" option only includes a fixed subset of fields that are available when the audit trail is stored in the DB.